# Does using compre_exchange with c++20 compare the value representations? (why doesn't this example agree)

Tags: c++, atomic, c++20

From this [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange)

> Atomically compares the object representation (until C++20)value representation (since C++20) of *this with that of expected, and if those are bitwise-equal, replaces the former with desired (performs read-modify-write operation). Otherwise, loads the actual value stored in *this into expected (performs load operation).

Hence using `C++20`, the `while` loop in the following code must be infinite but It's finite. Am I wrong or what's happening

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    char a{};
    int b{};
};
bool operator==(const S& lhs, const S& rhs) {
    return lhs.a == rhs.a && lhs.b == rhs.b;
}
int main() {

    S expected{ 'a', 2 };
    std::atomic<S> atomicS{ S{'a', 2} };

    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&(atomicS))[1] = 'e';
    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&(expected))[1] = 'f';

    while (atomicS.compare_exchange_strong(expected, S{ 'a',2 }));
    std::cout << "\nfinished";
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WWbq66)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This change (to use value representation instead of object representation) was done as part of [P0528R3](https://wg21.link/p0528r3) (the motivation and story can be found in [P0528R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0528r0.html)). As you can see under [cppreference's compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), neither gcc nor clang implement this feature yet. MSVC does on 19.28, but that's not available on compiler explorer, so I cannot check that to verify at the moment.

So at the moment, you're effectively verifying the old behavior.